# Extruding multiple polygons with multiple holes and texturing the combined shape

Tags: svg, three.js, textures, polygon

This question is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16118274/converting-svg-paths-with-holes-to-extruded-shapes-in-three-js). The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16121654/1691517) shows very nice way to extrude polygons that have holes (see [the excellent live example](http://jsfiddle.net/pHn2B/34/)). The main learning of the answer was that paths in three.js (r58) cannot have more than one moveTo command and it have to be in the start of the path, which means that path have to be broken by moveTos, so that moveTo start always a new path.

Extruding in three.js means that 2D paths are converted to 3D shapes using possible beveling. It is suitable for extruding texts to make 3D letters and words, but can be used also to extrude custom paths.

Now there arises two questions:

- how is it possible to handle polygons that have multiple hole-polygons and multiple non-hole-polygons?
- how is it possible to add a texture to generated shape as a whole?

I made an example of this as SVG in http://jsbin.com/oqomuj/1/edit:

[image]

The image is produced using this path:

```
<path d="
 M57.11,271.77 L57.11,218.33 L41.99,218.63 L105.49,165.77 L138.41,193.18 L138.41,172.2 L152.53,172.2 L152.53,204.93 L168.99,218.63 L153.21,218.63 L153.21,271.77Z
 M74.14,264.13 L105.49,264.13 L105.49,232.8 L74.14,232.8Z
 M115.35,250.7 L135.96,250.7 L135.96,232.61 L115.35,232.61Z
 M56.11,145.77 L56.11,92.33 L40.99,92.63 L104.49,39.77 L137.41,67.18 L137.41,46.2 L151.53,46.2 L151.53,78.93 L152.53,79.76 L155.55,77.23 L159.5,74.52 L168.65,69.81 L176.46,66.93 L188.04,64.16 L200.63,62.7 L213.65,62.7 L226.05,64.09 L234.83,66.06 L245.65,69.73 L252.87,73.27 L259.12,77.34 L262.63,80.33 L265.6,83.47 L268.01,86.76 L269.83,90.17 L271.08,93.68 L271.76,99.08 L271.04,104.64 L269.75,108.2 L267.87,111.63 L265.42,114.91 L262.44,118.01 L258.95,120.92 L255.02,123.63 L245.86,128.34 L238.06,131.22 L226.48,133.99 L213.88,135.44 L200.63,135.44 L188.04,133.99 L176.46,131.22 L168.65,128.34 L159.5,123.63 L155.55,120.92 L152.21,118.12 L152.21,145.77Z
 M73.14,138.13 L104.49,138.13 L104.49,106.8 L73.14,106.8Z
 M114.35,124.7 L134.96,124.7 L134.96,106.61 L114.35,106.61Z
 M207.26,117.33 L210.57,117.26 L216.87,116.53 L222.66,115.15 L227.8,113.18 L233.11,110 L236.34,106.99 L238.51,103.64 L239.42,100.48 L239.42,97.67 L238.51,94.51 L236.34,91.16 L233.11,88.15 L227.8,84.97 L222.66,83 L216.87,81.62 L210.57,80.89 L203.94,80.89 L197.65,81.62 L191.86,83 L186.71,84.97 L181.41,88.15 L178.18,91.16 L176.01,94.51 L175.1,97.67 L175.1,100.48 L176.01,103.64 L178.18,106.99 L181.41,110 L186.71,113.18 L191.86,115.15 L197.65,116.53 L203.94,117.26Z
"></path>
```

and this path converted to individual arrays of vertices:

```
var lower_house_material = [{x:57.11,y:271.77},{x:57.11,y:218.33},{x:41.99,y:218.63},{x:105.49,y:165.77},{x:138.42,y:193.18},{x:138.42,y:172.2},{x:152.53,y:172.2},{x:152.53,y:204.93},{x:168.99,y:218.63},{x:153.21,y:218.63},{x:153.21,y:271.77}];
var lower_house_hole_1 = [{x:74.14,y:264.13},{x:105.49,y:264.13},{x:105.49,y:232.8},{x:74.14,y:232.8}];
var lower_house_hole_2 = [{x:115.35,y:250.7},{x:135.96,y:250.7},{x:135.96,y:232.61},{x:115.35,y:232.61}];

var upper_house_material = [{x:56.11,y:145.77},{x:56.11,y:92.33},{x:40.99,y:92.63},{x:104.49,y:39.77},{x:137.42,y:67.18},{x:137.42,y:46.2},{x:151.53,y:46.2},{x:151.53,y:78.93},{x:152.53,y:79.76},{x:155.55,y:77.23},{x:159.5,y:74.52},{x:168.65,y:69.81},{x:176.46,y:66.93},{x:188.04,y:64.16},{x:200.63,y:62.7},{x:213.65,y:62.7},{x:226.05,y:64.1},{x:234.83,y:66.06},{x:245.65,y:69.73},{x:252.87,y:73.27},{x:259.12,y:77.35},{x:262.63,y:80.33},{x:265.6,y:83.47},{x:268.01,y:86.76},{x:269.84,y:90.17},{x:271.08,y:93.68},{x:271.76,y:99.08},{x:271.04,y:104.64},{x:269.75,y:108.2},{x:267.87,y:111.63},{x:265.42,y:114.91},{x:262.44,y:118.01},{x:258.96,y:120.92},{x:255.02,y:123.63},{x:245.86,y:128.34},{x:238.06,y:131.22},{x:226.48,y:133.99},{x:213.88,y:135.45},{x:200.63,y:135.45},{x:188.04,y:133.99},{x:176.46,y:131.22},{x:168.65,y:128.34},{x:159.5,y:123.63},{x:155.55,y:120.92},{x:152.21,y:118.12},{x:152.21,y:145.77}];
var upper_house_hole_1 = [{x:73.14,y:138.13},{x:104.49,y:138.13},{x:104.49,y:106.8},{x:73.14,y:106.8}];
var upper_house_hole_2 = [{x:114.35,y:124.7},{x:134.96,y:124.7},{x:134.96,y:106.61},{x:114.35,y:106.61}];
var upper_house_hole_3 = [{x:207.26,y:117.33},{x:210.57,y:117.26},{x:216.87,y:116.53},{x:222.66,y:115.15},{x:227.8,y:113.18},{x:233.11,y:110},{x:236.34,y:106.99},{x:238.51,y:103.64},{x:239.42,y:100.48},{x:239.42,y:97.67},{x:238.51,y:94.51},{x:236.34,y:91.16},{x:233.11,y:88.15},{x:227.8,y:84.97},{x:222.66,y:83},{x:216.87,y:81.62},{x:210.57,y:80.89},{x:203.94,y:80.89},{x:197.65,y:81.62},{x:191.86,y:83},{x:186.71,y:84.97},{x:181.41,y:88.15},{x:178.18,y:91.16},{x:176.01,y:94.51},{x:175.1,y:97.67},{x:175.1,y:100.48},{x:176.01,y:103.64},{x:178.18,y:106.99},{x:181.41,y:110},{x:186.71,y:113.18},{x:191.86,y:115.15},{x:197.65,y:116.53},{x:203.94,y:117.26}];
```

The question is, how this like structure can be converted to 3D object in three.js so that it can be extruded using `THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, extrusionSettings )` and after that textured as a whole?

I can examine the path data to know what hole belongs to what polygon and handle all as separate shapes, but because I want to use **one texture image across all the shapes**, I think the preferred way is to handle all material-polygons as one shape, and hole-polygons as other shape and use something like:

```
var shape = [lower_house_material, upper_house_material];
shape.holes = [lower_house_hole_1, lower_house_hole_2, upper_house_hole_1, upper_house_hole_2, upper_house_hole_3];
var 3d_geometry = THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape, extrusionSettings );
```

So the `3d_geometry` should be at the end one mesh to which I can append a texture this way:

```
var textureFront = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textureFront.png');
var textureSide = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textureSide.png');
var materialFront = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: textureFront } );
var materialSide = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: textureSide } );
var materialArray = [ materialFront, materialSide ];
var faceMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materialArray);
var final_mesh = new THREE.Mesh(3d_geometry, faceMaterial );
```

And one of the textures could be something like this (256x256px):

[image]

And texture applied:

[image]

And because the mesh is extruded, there is also 3D thickness on the above, but you got the idea of texturing.

I know that y-coordinates have to be flipped but it is a trivial task and not the point of my question, but if three.js has ready-made function for clipping y, it would be helpful.

I have spent hours to examine the three.js source code, examples and [documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/58/#Reference/Textures/Texture), but because the most frequent word there is "todo", it cannot help much. And I'm very newbie to three.js, I would think that this may be trivial task for some experienced three.js user.

UPDATE: And just to make sure, the hole polygons are always well-behaved, which means that hole polygons are always fully inside material-polygons and there are no duplicate vertices or self-intersections either in material-polygons or hole-polygons and all material-polygons have CW winding order and holes CCW.

UPDATE: Merging geometries was not a solution for texturing the whole extruded polygon set by one texture: http://jsfiddle.net/C5dga. The texture is repeated on all individual shapes, so merging geometries in this case has no real meaning. The solution could be possibly found on merging shapes before they are extruded, but not found solution for this yet.

Comment: This is what SVG filters were invented for. I'm not familiar with three.js syntax for them, but basically, you pull in the texture with an feImage and then do an feComposite operator="in" with the source graphic.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. That's true that filter-capable browsers can produce this like effect in SVG, but in this question I'm interested in texturing 3D shape in three.js for rendering the output in browser's webGL engine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can merge geometries as in the following snippet, resulting in just a single mesh. From your prior questions, you already know how to texture a single geometry.

```
var geometry1 = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape1, extrusionSettings );
var geometry2 = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( shape2, extrusionSettings );

geometry1.merge( geometry2 );

. . .

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry1, material );

scene.add( mesh );
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pHn2B/88/

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C5dga/13/ (with texture)

EDIT: As an alternative to creating separate geometries and using the `merge` utility, you can create a single geometry using the following pattern, instead:

```
var geometry1 = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( [ shape1, shape2 ], extrusionSettings );
```

EDIT: updated to three.js r.70

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried to add the texture on the whole mesh, but the texture renders separately on each shape: http://jsfiddle.net/C5dga/ Any ideas?

Comment: Yep. I think you know what you will have to do -- provide your own UV generator.

Comment: I have a bounding box generator (http://jsfiddle.net/C5dga/). It scales UV:s from geometry's coordinate space to range 0-1. But the problem is that those UV:s are generated in THREE.ExtrudeGeometry for every separate geometry before merging. I'd need some function to make UV mapping to merged geometry. So where should I provide my own UV generator?

Comment: And regarding the other part of my question: is there any method in three.js to convert array of vertices eg. [{x:56.11,y:145.77},{x:56.11,y:92.33},...] to shape (or path)? Or is it needed to use slow moveto and lineto methods also in cases where there are hundred or thousand of vertices?

Comment: You can edit the UVs manually to get what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/C5dga/1/ . I am hopeful you can solve any remaining issues yourself, and are able to accept this answer.

Comment: Fine! This works exactly in the way I want! Many thanks! If someone wonders what those numbers in custom UV generator means, I added the explanation: http://jsfiddle.net/C5dga/3/. I'll try to figure out something faster replacement for lineto() to avoid slowness due to function calls but if I cannot figure it out, I'll post a new question of it. You are hero!