# Three.js - technique for turning a transparent PNG into a 3D "card" with the geometry of the transparency

Tags: three.js, mesh, 3d-modelling

The goal is to turn any transparent PNG into a 3D card with a slight thickness and the geometry of the image minus transparency. For example, I'd like to take an image like this one: http://findicons.com/files/icons/730/soft/128/user_male.png and turn it into a card object with a slight thickness. However, the card should not be rectangular - its edges should follow the shape of the transparency in the image.

Is there any simple procedural way to accomplish this on any given PNG?

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124691/extruding-multiple-polygons-with-multiple-holes-and-texturing-the-combined-shape for how to extrude a shape and texture it. It remains to convert your PNG to an SVG, perhaps, and then to an array of points to form the outline.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. Maybe I'll try converting the PNG's alpha channel to a solid color and then using potrace to turn that into a path. Then I would need to import that path into THREE.js and then using the technique used in the linked article. Not sure how to do all of that technically yet, but it sounds theoretically possible.